# Delete User in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with the flutter when I want to delete a user with Firebase.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.delete()
  .then((value) => Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>LoginScreen())
  )
);
```

Comment: and what's that problem ?

Comment: When I click the delete button, the user is not deleted

Comment: can you describe exactly what happens, we can't help if there is no clarification or the code where you call that method and what behavior on the screen you're facing when you try to delete the user.

Comment: I put that code in the onPress function of the delete button when but when I click to delete that user it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The Doc says:

```
  /// Deletes and signs out the user.
  ///
  /// **Important**: this is a security-sensitive operation that requires the
  /// user to have recently signed in. If this requirement isn't met, ask the
  /// user to authenticate again and then call [User.reauthenticateWithCredential].
```

So check that u are singed in with the current user before you delete.

Then then next point is before your navigate sign out the user with:

```
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
```

If it wont work try this delete Method:

```
 var delete = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('users')
                                  .doc(uid)
                                  .delete();
```